Raspberry - cannot configure a fixed IP address
I want to configure a fixed IP address on my Raspberry 4.
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.188  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 2003:cc:716:e200:307d:f3f6:9362:c69c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::782c:e11e:6956:5ea1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:3a:dd:38:4c:59  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1284  bytes 149120 (145.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 198  bytes 42791 (41.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 19  bytes 2311 (2.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19  bytes 2311 (2.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d8:3a:dd:38:4c:5a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG    1002   0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1002   0        0 eth0

The /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf looks like this:
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#       man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#       and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#       dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#       not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#       few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.2.6
netmask 255.255.255.0
static routers=192.168.2.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.2.1

The Network Manager is not running:
$ sudo nmcli -p connection show
Error: NetworkManager is not running.

$ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager
○ NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)

$ sudo systemctl status dhcpcd
● dhcpcd.service - DHCP Client Daemon on all interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-06-27 13:38:26 CEST; 8min ago
       Docs: man:dhcpcd(8)
    Process: 542 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 583 (dhcpcd)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 3906)
        CPU: 616ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
             ├─583 "dhcpcd: [manager] [ip4] [ip6]"
             ├─584 "dhcpcd: [privileged proxy]"
             ├─585 "dhcpcd: [network proxy]"
             ├─586 "dhcpcd: [control proxy]"
             ├─744 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0
             └─879 "dhcpcd: [BPF ARP] end0 192.168.2.188"

Jun 27 13:38:33 evcc-Raspberry dhcpcd[584]: end0: Router Advertisement from fe80::464e:6dff:fe58:9fd6
Jun 27 13:38:33 evcc-Raspberry dhcpcd[584]: end0: adding address 2003:cc:716:e200:307d:f3f6:9362:c69c/64
Jun 27 13:38:33 evcc-Raspberry dhcpcd[584]: end0: adding route to 2003:cc:716:e200::/64
Jun 27 13:38:33 evcc-Raspberry dhcpcd[584]: end0: requesting DHCPv6 information
Jun 27 13:38:33 evcc-Raspberry dhcpcd[584]: end0: adding default route via fe80::464e:6dff:fe58:9fd6
Jun 27 13:38:34 evcc-Raspberry dhcpcd[584]: end0: REPLY6 received from fe80::464e:6dff:fe58:9fd6
Jun 27 13:38:34 evcc-Raspberry dhcpcd[584]: end0: refresh in 86400 seconds
Jun 27 13:38:38 evcc-Raspberry dhcpcd[584]: end0: leased 192.168.2.188 for 86400 seconds
Jun 27 13:38:38 evcc-Raspberry dhcpcd[584]: end0: adding route to 192.168.2.0/24
Jun 27 13:38:38 evcc-Raspberry dhcpcd[584]: end0: adding default route via 192.168.2.1

I rebooted several times, however I just get a dhcp IP address 192.168.2.188 (within the dhcp range of the router) and not the fixed IP address of 192.168.2.6. How can I make it work?

First, are you sure the system is using dhclient as its DHCP client? Second, are you sure this particular configuration goes in dhclient.conf?

Yes, the dhcp client is running. I added the status.

Network Manager is not running why not?

I disabled the NetworkManager!

That's the wrong config file. You're trying to configure dhcpcd, but the configuration file belongs to dhclient – ISC dhclient is a completely different DHCP client program from dhcpcd. (It's commonly found on regular Debian.) The parameters should most likely go in /etc/dhcpcd.conf.
